# ¿Por que mi consulta SQL marca error de sintaxis cuando pongo DESC?

Tags: sql-server, sql

hola comunidad tengo un problema con esta consulta ya revise la sintaxy de como usar order by con desc el cual tengo este problema si quito el desc si compila muchas gracias por su atención

¿Cual es la edad maxima, la edad minima y el salario promedio por departamento? (ordenarlo de manera descendente por nombre de departamento)

```
SELECT MAX(edad) AS 'edad maxima',MIN(edad) as 'edad minima',AVG(sueldo) AS 'sueldo promedio',TD.nombre 
FROM empleado AS TE
INNER JOIN departamento AS TD  ON  TE.id_departamento=TD.id_departamento  
group by TD.nombre desc;
```

EL CUAL EL ID SQL SERVER ME ARROGA UN MSJ

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 72
> Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'desc'.

Comment: ¿Estas tratando de buscar los datos de un usuario o estas listando todos los datos?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por qué la palabra reservada `DESC` está destinada al ordenamiento del conjunto de resultados que la consulta devuelve.

Para lograr lo anterior se usa `desc` en conjunto con `order by` indicando entre estás dos la(s) columna(s) por la(s) cual(es) deseas hacer el ordenamiento

Entonces para este caso tu consulta debería quedar al final como:

```
group by TD.nombre
ORDER BY columnaElegida DESC
```

**Referencia**

- [Para un conocimiento en detalle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax)

Answer (score 4):

Tienes que volver a llamar a que columna vas a ordenar.

Secuencia:

```
SELECT MAX(edad) AS edad_maxima, MIN(edad) AS edad_minima, AVG(sueldo) AS 
sueldo_promedio, TD.nombre 
FROM empleado AS TE
INNER JOIN departamento AS TD ON TE.id_departamento = TD.id_departamento  
GROUP BY TD.nombre ORDER BY TD.nombre DESC;
```